# ORACLE: The best way to parse JSON into collection of object types

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an object type: `create type t_ref_rec is object(id number, name varchar2(256));`

And a table type: `create type t_ref_tbl is table of t_ref_rec;`

I parse JSON onto a collection like this:

```
declare
    var_ref_tbl t_ref_tbl;
begin
    ...
    select
        t_ref_rec(id, name)
    bulk collect into
        var_ref_tbl
    from
        json_table
        (
            '[{"id":1, "name":"one"}, {"id":2, "name":"two"}]',
            '$[*]'
            columns
            (
                id number path '$.id',
                name varchar2 path '$.name'
            )
        );
    ....
end;
```

Is there a better way to parse data from JSON into a collection of `t_ref_tbl` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on 19c or higher, the best way is to state your object as the return type for a `JSON_value` call and the database will map it for you:

```
create type t_ref_rec is object(id number, name varchar2(256));
/
create type t_ref_tbl is table of t_ref_rec;
/

select json_value (
  '[{"id":1, "name":"one"}, {"id":2, "name":"two"}]',
  '$' returning t_ref_tbl 
) obj
from   dual;

OBJ(ID, NAME)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------
T_REF_TBL(T_REF_REC(1, 'one'), T_REF_REC(2, 'two'))
```

The `on mismatch` clause enable you to define what happens if there's a [difference between the JSON document and the object type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/clauses-used-in-functions-and-conditions-for-json.html#GUID-21FE887D-5D7B-43BB-A1A8-B26B8924B290).

Comment: Wow, nice! Another question is what to do if the property names do not match in the object type and in JSON?
For example, if JSON is '[{"id":1, "my_name":"one"}, {"id":2, "my_name":"two"}]' how do I match "my_name" in JSON and " name" in object type?

Comment: Sounds like the subject for a new question! There has to be an exact 1:1 match on the attribute names in the document and object. By default the database ignores these differences so mismatches are null. To get around this you'll either need to rename the attributes in the object or JSON; you can do use JSON_transform to rename attributes in the JSON.